# excel map values to same key column

Tags: excel

From a text file i copy 10 lines of text in the format productName#qty.

First time around it could be in the following order. I paste this onto excel and separate the data by #

```
A#10 ->   A   10
D#25 ->   D   25
```

Second time around it could be in the following order. I do the same as before.

```
B#10 ->   B   10
A#12 ->   A   12
```

I want to merge the 2 sets of data and want the output to be something like this

```
A  10   12
B       10
D  25
```

Any help on how to do this. I don't know programming or macros, so any detailed description will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column for 'time around' and create a PivotTable with that for COLUMNS, Product for ROWS and Sum of Qty for Sigma VALUES:

[image: SO23894074 example]